# with fast scroll, twentmax animations shot with scrollmagic do not work correctly

Tags: animation, fullpage.js, scrollmagic, gsap

I have a problem, I am making a page with fullpage.js, I am launching animations with tweenLite every time I reach a section with Scrollmagic.

The problem is the following:

If I move in the normal order of the sections, one by one, the animations come out correctly, but when I jump, from the first section to the last one for example, the animations do not complement each other correctly everything gets decontrolled, I leave the sample of the page, so you can better understand what is happening.

Is there any optimal way to do this process, thanks in advance for the help.

http://pagina.gestionahora.co/